# How to remove a node from an xml file using php and store it in another xml file?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have an xml file like this which have some alerts
alert.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<alerts>
  <alert>
    <id>3</id>
    <msg_type>1</msg_type>
    <msg>Some Message</msg>
    <url>Some Link</url>
    <status>0</status>
    <create_date>1388049941</create_date>
    <update_date>1388052529</update_date>
  </alert>
  <alert>
    <id>6</id>
    <msg_type>1</msg_type>
    <msg>Some Message</msg>
    <url>Some Link</url>
    <status>0</status>
    <create_date>1388049941</create_date>
    <update_date>1388052529</update_date>
  </alert>
  <alert>
    <id>14</id>
    <msg_type>1</msg_type>
    <msg>Some Message</msg>
   <url>Some Link</url>
    <status>0</status>
    <create_date>1388049941</create_date>
    <update_date>1388052529</update_date>
  </alert>
  <alert>
    <id>24</id>
    <msg_type>1</msg_type>
    <msg>Some Message</msg>
    <url>Some Link</url>
    <status>0</status>
    <create_date>1388049941</create_date>
    <update_date>1388052529</update_date>
  </alert>
</alerts>
```

now I am reading this file using php like this to find a record.

```
$alerts = new simpleXMLElement($filename, null, true);
$search_mediums1 = $alerts->xpath('alert[msg_type=1]');

$search_mediums = array_reverse($search_mediums1);
foreach ($search_mediums as $arr_alert) {
    if ($arr_alert->id == $my_id) {
        // i want some code here to delete that node
        // and put it into some other xml with same structure file
        break;
    }
}
```

I have find some solutions with `DOMDocument();` class but I am using here `simpleXMLElement`
Its working fine to find the record of desired `msg_type=1` and `id=$my_id` now I want to remove the node from `alert.xml` file, if find and put it into `other xml file` which have same format as `alert.xml`. How can I remove the node from 'alert.xml' and put it in another xml file ?

Comment: [There doesn't seem to have a `removeChild()` method or alike in SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). While it _may_ still be doable, I would recommend to use `DOMDocument` instead.

Comment: ya but i want to find the node with some condition also using xpath

Comment: `DOMDocument` has XPath support too: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Comment: so how this code is modified with DOMDocument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved one issue that remove the desired node using `dom_import_simplexml` method as follows

```
$alerts = new simpleXMLElement($filename, null, true);
$search_mediums1 = $alerts->xpath('alert[msg_type=1]');

$search_mediums = array_reverse($search_mediums1);
foreach($search_mediums as $arr_alert)
{
    if($arr_alert->id==$my_id)
    {
       // Deleting the Node 
        $domRef = dom_import_simplexml($arr_alert);
        $domRef->parentNode->removeChild($domRef);
        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $dom->loadXML($alerts->asXML());
        $dom->save($filename);


       // moving the Node into another file
        $target=new DOMDocument();
        $target->formatOutput = true;
        $target->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $target_content = file_get_contents($target_filename);
        $target->loadXML($target_content);
        $target->documentElement->appendChild($target->importNode($domRef,true));
        $target->save($target_filename);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i find the anwer in my code with help of @Passerby. thanks a lot Passerby

Answer (score 2):

According to [PHP Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php), `SimpleXMLElement` doesn't have a `removeChild()` method or alike, so you may have better luck with `DOMDocument` instead.

Changing this code to `DOM` is straightforward, although `DOM` codes will seem a little long and verbose...

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML(/* XML content */);
$xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodeList=$xpath->query('alert[msg_type=1]');
$myID=14; // Just to demonstrate
foreach($nodeList as $node)
{
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child)
    {
        if($child->nodeName=="id")
        {
            if($child->textContent==$myID)
            {
                $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

[**Online demo**](http://3v4l.org/bofXs)

The output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<alerts>
  <alert>
    <id>3</id>
    <msg_type>1</msg_type>
    <msg>Some Message</msg>
    <url>Some Link</url>
    <status>0</status>
    <create_date>1388049941</create_date>
    <update_date>1388052529</update_date>
  </alert>
  <alert>
    <id>6</id>
    <msg_type>1</msg_type>
    <msg>Some Message</msg>
    <url>Some Link</url>
    <status>0</status>
    <create_date>1388049941</create_date>
    <update_date>1388052529</update_date>
  </alert>

  <alert>
    <id>24</id>
    <msg_type>1</msg_type>
    <msg>Some Message</msg>
    <url>Some Link</url>
    <status>0</status>
    <create_date>1388049941</create_date>
    <update_date>1388052529</update_date>
  </alert>
</alerts>
```

You can see the `<alert>` with `<id>14</id>` is removed.

---

Additional:

To move the deleted node to another document, do this:

```
$target=new DOMDocument();
$target->loadXML(/* xml */);
/* ... */
if($child->textContent==$myID)
{
    $target->documentElement->appendChild($target->importNode($node,true));
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
/* ... */
```

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/avFJI)

Comment: thanks bro !! i tried and use the dom_import_simplexml method and its worked now how can i put that node into another xml file

Comment: thanks!! i tried your code in my own answer and its working. i am updating my own answer for issue-2. please see it. i am really thankful to for your help. thanks bro !!